# TASVEG Categorising Symbols

Tags: qgis, symbology

I am trying to find an easier method to align the symbols from TASVEG 3.0 with those that I have in my layer in QGIS. I can do it manually and alter each individual symbol that I have categorised but there are over 150 vegetation communities (different symbols).

I am wondering if anyone has an easier way to do this or knows of a download file possibly an SVG with the symbols preloaded.

Comment: Do you have TASVEG 3.0, or are you just trying to match its symbology?  I believe that it comes with all the symbology .lyr files (for ArcGIS), and you could convert these to SLD for QGIS.

Comment: I can't find a way to convert the lyr files to SLD. The only way I can find is by converting it in ArcGIS which I do not have.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to DPIPWE who own the TASVEG dataset (and presumably licenced you to use it).  They are approachable and will likely convert the included .lyr symbology file into a .sld file if you ask them.

Otherwise find somebody else with ArcGIS who can do it for you.